# Css changes not working with synchronous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to use `async : false` to make **synchronous** ajax call for some reasons because i want to wait for every request to complete to execute the next one.

But it doesn't work, the css changes `$(...).css( "opacity" , "1" )` is not working .

But when I switch to `async : true` it works !!

```
$( ".foo" ).each(function( i , item ) {

    $(item ).find(".ajaxLoader").css( "opacity" , "1" );    
    $.ajax({ 
        async    : false,
        ....
        complete : function(){ $(item ).find(".ajaxLoader").css( "opacity" , "0" ); }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: because the page did not get time to redraw before you lock it up with the synchronous request.

Comment: @epascarello No there is enough time because the ajax call take a couple seconds

Comment: No, there is not time..... that is why you have the issue.

Comment: @epascarello First what do you mean by lock it up with the synchronous request ? the page is locked while synchronous ajax calls so i can't do nothing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is because you lock UI using unrelevant synchronous ajax call just like [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192964/css-changes-not-working-with-synchronous-ajax-call#comment-67651938) is telling you. Don't use sync requests... 
You probably don't need any loop anyway because you could get all relevant data from just one ajax call i guess BUT if you want to make some ajax requests (async this time!) sequential, then you can use:

```
var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
$(".foo").get().forEach(function(foo) {      
  d = d.then(function() {
    return $.ajax({
      /*async: true,*/
      ....
      beforeSend: function(){
        $(foo).find(".ajaxLoader").css("opacity", "1");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $(foo).find(".ajaxLoader").css("opacity", "0");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its such an interesting question/task for me to solve this. I enjoyed it a lot.

May be it will **look a bit odd** to you, I used `0.5 seconds` delay for my testing but you can optimize code more as per your scenario.

Working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55v2L9ro/)**

Hope this will help you.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `beforeSend()` function of `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend(){
        $(item ).find(".ajaxLoader").css( "opacity" , "1" );
    },
    ...
})
```

Doc link : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you have `.ajaxLoader` div in full height and width this div cause issue for solve that you better hide that div on success of ajax response, here you go please.

```
$.ajax({ 
    async    : false,
    ....
    beforeSend(){
        $(item ).find(".ajaxLoader").css( "opacity" , "1" );   
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $(item ).find(".ajaxLoader").css( "opacity" , "0").hide();   
    }
});
```